# An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code in MVC 5 Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to create MVC 5 application using Visual Studio 2015 that consist a forums(discussions).

Followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcMcz5rrs5w) and try to configure [MVCForum](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MVCForum) with [MVCForum.Identity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MVCForum.Identity)

So for that I used to integrate already built system(mvcforum) with my MVC 5 Project When I Compile it hasn't any error but when I debug this I'm getting following error in **Global.asax.cs** File

> An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

[image]

Comment: can you look into the `View Detail` to see some more specific info?

Comment: in inner exception messenger section  `A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)`

Comment: Check if your connectionstring is correct. Also check if you sql server service is alive.

Comment: It clearly states that there is some SQL connection error. Show your web.config, give some more information about database you are using and code, which is use to connect to it.

Comment: You should also check if your IIS AppPool has enough permission on your database